# GraphViz: Windows PATH not set with new installer, issue when calling from R

Tags: r, graphviz

In an R library, I am using the `dot` program (from GraphViz) to produce some graphics (usually in png format). `dot` is a usual executable and I execute it through the `system` R command. Until now, everything was running fine because the GraphViz installer was adding `dot` to the PATH environment variable. I was just asking users to install GraphViz.

Since version 2.31 (see http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php), GraphViz no longer updates the PATH environment variable and, hence, calling `dot` fails (this is not a surprise). Because the users of the library are usually not computer experts, I cannot ask them to update the PATH in order to include GraphViz.

The library is distributed on the CRAN. For this reason, I cannot distribute executable (or any compiled code). I mainly need a solution for Windows, since this not seems to affect Linux or Mac.

Any idea, on how I can proceed in order to produce the image file? Or find `dot`?

Comment: What is `dot` ? There's no such package listed at CRAN.  Please explain what program or function you are calling from which application.

Comment: `dot` is the name of one of the executable of GraphViz. I am executing dot using R `system` command

Comment: In that case, just distribute an updated PATH specification as part of the `.Rprofile` file that these "not computer experts" call when they start `R` running.

Comment: Sorry, the question was maybe not be clear enough (hence I edited the question). But I do not know where GraphViz is located (otherwise, I can just use the full path in the R `system` command)

Comment: So go find it in the C:/program files (or programfilesx86) directory, or wherever you installed it to.

Comment: But I do not know where the user have installed it

Comment: If you have users installing to a nonstandard location, you're pretty much stuck.  I recommend you take some alternative approach such as not usin GraphViz,  and in the meantime remove this question.  It doesn't seem to be generating any interest here.

Comment: @MatthiasStuder would it be possible to use the package [Rgraphviz](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/bioc/html/Rgraphviz.html) for your `R` library `WeightedCluster`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We decided not to set PATH during installation. We had a lot of trouble doing this in a portable way, given our limited knowledge of Windows in its many forms. The huge downside of getting it wrong is that you trash some poor "not computer expert"'s PATH and they can't recover. We made a note to this effect on the Windows download page for Graphviz. I agree about setting .Rprofile. At least you limit the damage if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you plan to use the same default installation direction pattern in future release (such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz(VersionNumber)? Maybe I can check for possible default directories? Those specifying another installation directory should be able to specify the path.

Answer (score 8):

You have a valid concern, which is why we tried to alter the PATH in previous releases. First,  yes, we will probably keep `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz(VersionNumber)` as the default installation path. Second, if anyone can tell us how to alter the PATH safely at install time,  we would appreciate it. Another possibility is to have the installation process set a Graphviz specific variable like GVPATH that records the directory containing dot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Having a specific environment variable (like GVPATH) would be a nice solution in my case.