# display trees of discrepancy analysis in R (using graphviz)

Tags: r, graphviz, traminer

I am doing a discrepancy analysis in R and have problems displaying the tree with graphviz. I did everything as described in Studer et al 2011 (in: Guillet et al: Advances in Knowledge Discovery and Management). I use the disstree command to build my tree called tree.lcp and then try to display it with graphviz:

```
seqtree2dot(tree.lcp, filename="hh.lcp", seqdata=seqhh)

shell("dot -Tsvg -O hh.lcp.dot")
```

There is no problem with the first command but the second brings this error message:

> Can not find command "dot" .
>   Error messages:
>   1: command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c dot -Tsvg -O hh.lcp.dot' gave status 1
>   2: In shell("dot -Tsvg -O hh.lcp.dot") :
>     'dot -Tsvg -O hh.lcp.dot' process failed - error code 1

I suppose it has something to do with th path command (see [GraphViz: Windows PATH not set with new installer, issue when calling from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334805/graphviz-windows-path-not-set-with-new-installer-issue-when-calling-from-r)) but I installed GraphViz to C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.36 which I understand is the default.

Any idea, where the problem lies? And how could I include the path in the shell-command if the problem is still the path command?

Thanks! Katharina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the path as follows

```
shell(paste('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.36/dot"','-Tsvg -O hh.lcp.dot'))
```

However, if you want to plot a tree from dissimilarities between sequences, you are probably better to use the newer simplified `seqtreedisplay` function that generates the plot directly from the `seqtree` object, i.e., the outcome of the `seqtree` function. Normally, `seqtreedisplay` should find Graphviz by itself.

For more details, look at the help page by typing `help(seqtreedisplay)`.

Answer (score 2):

The latest TraMineR version has a new function that run everything directly. The function is called seqtreedisplay.

`seqtreedisplay(tree.lcp, type="d")`

Try running: `TraMineR.checkupdates()` to know if you have the latest stable version.

Comment: @ gilbert @Mattias Studer: The seqtreedisplay, or more precisely the disstreedisplay command was exactly what I needed. Graphviz was found automatically and I have the trees now. Thanks! Katharina

Comment: @Katharina Please vote for and accept one of the answer (Gilbert's seems more precise). If you do so, futur readers experiencing similar issue will now how to solve it.